# What to do when a JSON document uses a removed class?

Tags: .net, json, ravendb, json.net

I recently had to remove a class, that is used by many json documents.
Now deserialization fails because the removed class doesn't exist anymore.

The error that is thrown looks like this:

> Error resolving type specified in JSON 'MyClass, MyAssembly'.

And here the json document:

```
{
  "$type": "MyClass, MyAssembly",
  "Property": "Value"
}
```

I'm using `TypeNameHandling.All`.

What can I do?

Answer (score 2):

Use TypeNameHandling.None or TypeNameHandling.Auto

Comment: I tried that before and it didn't work. However, I already found a workaround for my problem. I restored the class and removed it contents, so raven can find the type when deserializing.